# Proguard fails when build target set to 16 but compiles at api level 17

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard, java-compiler-api

I can debug and run my app fine on 4.1.2 (api 16) and on 4.2.2 (api 17). If I try to export the application for production when the build is set to 17 it will work fine but if i lower the target to 17 i get a few errors the main one is

Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.images.a: can't find referenced method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable[] getCompoundDrawablesRelative()' in class android.widget.TextView

Not sure why its throwing that error or why it works for one api level but not the other?

Here is my proguard config file

```
 -optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontobfuscate

-keepclassmembers public class org.springframework {
    public *;
}

-dontwarn com.amazonaws.**
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.**
-dontwarn org.springframework.**
-dontwarn com.emilsjolander.**



-keep class com.amazonaws.**                            { *; }
-keep class org.springframework.**                      { *; }
-keep class com.fasterxml.**                            { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.**                             { *; }

-keep class com.emilsjolander.** { *; } 


-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}



-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reported method doesn't exist in earlier versions of Android. ProGuard warns about the possible inconsistency in the application. In practice, it's OK; the GMS library handles the versions properly. You can tell ProGuard to proceed:

```
-dontwarn android.widget.TextView
```